# I need to checkout single folder from a Bitbucket Git repo

Tags: git, bitbucket

I have a repo that contains about 20 folders, created when I converted from SVN to Git.  Is it possible to checkout a single folder from a Git repository (on Bitbucket)?  Or do I have to make each of those folders a separate repo?

Comment: The answer is: yes. Unless you like to jump through (many) hoops, adn still end up with a limited solution

Comment: *Yes* to which question?

Comment: Yes to "Or do I have to make each of those folders a separate repo". There's a reason why you should try to ask a single clear question :) Anyhow, I hope I amused you with an approach that could work in my answer below.

Comment: or of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/600079/is-there-any-way-to-clone-a-git-repositorys-sub-directory-only

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Edit** Sparse checkouts could be basically this but better (see linked questions). Only, my answer takes care to do a *shallow* clone ***as well*** as doing only the sparse checkout.

You could hack it in two (well, roughly) steps:

1. checkout a shallow copy

   ```
   cd /tmp
   git clone --depth=1 --bare git@myhosted_repo/project.git

   (cd project.git && git branch master)
   ```
2. now - setup your working tree (separately)

   ```
   mkdir /tmp/workdir
   cd /tmp/workdir
   git init .

   # add the shallow clone as a remote
   git remote add --fetch shallow /tmp/project.git
   ```
3. the real hack:

   ```
   # read a subtree from the remote, shallow branch
   git read-tree --prefix somedir -u shallow/master:testcases/
   ```

   (assuming your repo has a directory called `testcases`)

You'd end up with a working dir containing just the files from `testcases/` in a subdirectory called `somedir`

The upshot:

- It gets only a single revision from the hosted repo. Good(TM)
- It only ever checks out the single subfolder from that revision. Good(TM)
- It's arcane. It will work especially bad if you intend to put `somedir` in some other repo (subtree merges can be done, but I wouldn't burn my fingers there)

Comment: Failing on on git branch master step. 
Then fetch gives warning: reject refs/remotes/shallow/master because shallow roots are not allowed to be updated. 
Also, fatal: Not a valid object name shallow/master:testcases...

Comment: @jrosell of course, shallow clones have limitations. If you look at the question, you see an example of a situation where shallow clones could be useful. Yours is not. You can unshallow your clone: `git fetch --unshallow origin` in your cloned repo